# Error in image retrieval using url

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web-services, error-handling

How can i resolve this error? Will someone please help me about this. Big Thanks to anyone who will help me.

[image i was trying to retrieve](http://sgpost.atwebpages.com/images/facebook.png)

[image]

Comment: please provide the code you where using to retrieve the image

Comment: Well i am trying to retrieve it via its URL.

Answer (score 0):

The image (http://sgwebpost.atwebpages.com/images/rosa.png) which you are trying to retrieve does not exist, even sgwebpost.atwebpages.com host does not exist. I just tried accessing url and host both via curl. Both failed.

Comment: i was playing with it last night.
http://sgpost.atwebpages.com/images/facebook.png

Comment: looks like your server is down.. can you restart your apache server ?

Comment: No. I am using Freehosting.

Comment: then you should contact your hosting service .. i think their server is down or in some problem.. you can access this via curl command and inspect the headers. From command prompt try this:                            curl -i "http://sgpost.atwebpages.com/images/facebook.png"